# Tengo el siguiente mensaje de error Uncaught ReferenceError: EXISTENCIAS is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
function llenar(v_op) {
$('#TablaSucursal').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
       "url": "/Control/LlenaSucursal",
       "type": "GET",
        "datatype": "json",
        "data": { v_op: v_op },
         },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "id_sucursal" },
        { "data": "tipo" },
        { "data": "nombre" },
        { "data": "servicio" },
        { "data": "folio" },
        {
          "data": function (x, y, z) {
         return "<button onclick='MyFuncion(" + x.tipo + ")'>" + x.tipo +.id_sucursal + "</button>";                                
         }

           }
        ],
      "destroy": true,
     "language": {
                    "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/Spanish.json",
                    "emptyTable": "Informacion no encontrada"
                }
            });
        }           

    });//fin del ready

    function MyFuncion(Op1) {                        
        console.info(Op1);                        
    }
```

Alguna idea de como pasar el parametro porque si pongo un parametro fijo funciona

Comment: En donde usas la variable `EXISTENCIAS`?

Comment: la variable que me regresa el ajax x.tipo contiene la palabra existencia, la cual pretendo pasar via parametro a la funcion, MyFunction, si paso algun argumento fijo como MyFuncion(2) funciona pero si paso el valor que me regresa el ajax me marca ese error quizas la sintaxis este incorrecta

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas escapar las comillas asi:

```
return "<button onclick='MyFuncion(\"" + x.tipo + "\")'>" + x.tipo +.id_sucursal + "</button>";
```

Comment: Excelente , respuesta , te debo un par de drinks, saludoss..